# 'gradlew eclipse' command is not working

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradlew

I have checked in code from the following URL

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples

Now I am try to build the code and give the command `'gradlew eclipse'`

and I am getting 522 error code. Could you please help us to resolve the erro

Comment: ..but why git tag? I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eclipse` task is not available in the root project because eclipse plugin is not applied on that project.  Add

```
apply plugin:'eclipse'
```

near the top of build.gradle and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If your on a mac your problem is you need to do ./gradlew eclipse, but if you are on a pc, maybe you need to be in a certain folder to do the gradlew command.