# Project is missing requuiered library - jar files are missing

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar, classpath

I have a gradle project imported from Git which uses the ZXing library. After getting the library myself Eclipse shows me the error that several Jar Files are missing, even though I had them all exported in the Classpath file:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="bug/lib/osgi.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/BarcodeReader.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/basic/BarcodeReader.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-nio-4.0.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/httpmime-4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/mailapi.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/pop3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="zxingorg/web/WEB-INF/lib/smtp.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
</classpath>
```

Can someone tell how to fix this problem besides downloading all the jar files manually?

Comment: Just run `gradlew eclipse`?

Comment: Does not work, the project has no gradle task by the name "eclipse" since the project has been initially buid in IntelliJ.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231458/10871900? You can remove the eclipse plugin after that

Comment: Or just import it as gradle project

Comment: Yes, that helped but I had to move several classes to resolve some minor package errors. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have a bunch of resolution errors, most of the classes seem to be in the wrong package.

Comment: @MetalBrush Maybe they are in the wrong package, maybe the source folder is configured wrong. How would someone know that without any information?